# How can I cancel auto closing tags in TinyMce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg, rte

TinyMce by default try to close html tags in rawHTML editor mode.

For example:

```
<p>sample text<strong>text</p>
```

automaticaly modified to

```
<p>sample text<strong>text</strong></p>
```

How can I cancel this functionality?

Answer (score -1):

This is not the fault of tinymce. What you have here is non-valid html so your browser will try to make it valid adding a closing strong tag.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Because when you try <b> tag - it automatically replaced to <strong> tag. I think it's tinymce feature.

Comment: Apparently there isn't any possibility except patch source code.

Comment: thats because the b-tag is deprecated, but this has nothing to do with the auto-completion of tags! if you wish you can use b-tag though (so do i for compatibility reasons)